# Intent Animation Does not Works

Tags: android, android-animation

At `first Screen(exitIntent)` i got the Animation but i didn't get the Animation at `2nd Intent(EntenIntent)`'I am using the

```
@override
PendingTransition(R.layout.animation, R.layout.wavescale);
```

at onCreate Method.

Why Animation does not works ,Can any one Explain

Comment: You really need to provide some details and code, otherwise I doubt anyone will be able to answer

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeScreen.class);
  intent.putExtra("value1", hashMap);
  intent.putExtra("value2", hashMap2);
  intent.putExtra("value", OrganiZationName);
  startActivity(intent);
   Anmationclass.this.finish();
         overridePendingTransition(R.layout.animation, R.layout.wavescale);

Comment: i didn't get the wavscale animation for Next Intent

Answer (score 0):

Try to finish your activity after overridePendingTransition or I just tried it If I use startActivityforResult the back transition doesn't show